# How to import a module in Python in a file that is both used as a __main__ and is imported by a file in a different directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Say I am using Python 3 (and hence absolute imports) and my directory structure looks like this:

```
> package:
    > sub_directory
        __init__.py
        sub_dir_file.py
        sub_dir_file2.py
    __init__.py
    main_dir_file.py
```

In the file `sub_dir_file.py` I wish to import a function from `sub_dir_file2.py`. The catch is, I want to be able to run `sub_dir_file.py` with `__name__ == '__main__'`, **as well as** import it in `main_dir_file.py`. Hence, if in `sub_dir_file.py` I use a relative import:

```
from .sub_dir_file2 import some_function
```

the module executes perfectly fine when run from `main_dir_file.py`, but throws an error when executed directly (as the relative import cannot be executed when `__name__ == '__main__'`. If I however use a normal absolute import, `sub_dir_file.py` will execute as a main, but cannot be imported from `main_dir_file.py`.

What would be the most elegant way of solving this problem? One obvious solution seems to be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sub_dir_file2 import some_function
else:
    from .sub_dir_file2 import some_function
```

However, it doesn't seem very pythonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the relative import syntax `from .sub_dir_file2 import some_function` or eventually the absolute syntax `from package.sub_directory.sub_dir_file2 import some_function`.

Then, in order to call one of the package sub module, it is simpler to use the [-m option](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) of the python interpreter to execute its content as the `__main__` module.

> Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the
>   **main** module.
>
> Since the argument is a module name, you must not give a file
>   extension (.py). The module name should be a valid absolute Python
>   module name, but the implementation may not always enforce this (e.g.
>   it may allow you to use a name that includes a hyphen).

For example:

```
> python -m package.main_dir_file
> python -m package.sub_directory.sub_dir_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `main()` function invoked if name is `__main__`. It's a good habit anyway, as far as I'm aware.

That way you can just call the imported module's `main()` yourself. It has other benefits, too, like allowing you to test or re-invoke the module without necessarily executing the file every time.